# Angular - Sidenav Content Has No Scroll Bar

Tags: angular, angular-material, scrollbar, sidenav

I'm using a sidenav in my Angular app and set the `router-outlet` as my `sidenav-content`, doing it this way I dont have a scroll bar in the `sidenav-content` even though I have components that overflow the Y axis.

I'm still able to scroll the page and eveything is fine, I just find annoying that I don't have a scroll bar.

**What could I do to fix this?**

##### app.component.html

```html
<mat-sidenav-container autosize class="h-100">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
        <mat-nav-list>
            ...
        </mat-nav-list>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting your router-outlet inside a div, then
on your css:

```
.sampleDivClass {
  overflow-y auto
}
``
```

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

if the entire page is scrolling when you just wanted the sidenav content to be scrollable you can try setting the overflow of the container hidden and set the overflow of only the sidenav content to auto

Comment: the sidenav itself doesn't scroll, all the behaviour is correct! The sidenav is static and the sidenav-content is scrollable, the problem is that there is no scroll bar on the screen